# Update udev after fdisk run

Tags: linux, gentoo, fdisk, udev

How to update /dev directory after creation of new partition on a disk?
I have the udev installed, it works perfectly except this. The new devices appear only on reboot.

Answer (score 3):

Command `partprobe` from `sys-block/parted` also does the job well.  Use is like this:

```
# partprobe
```

or for a particular device only (e.g. /dev/sda):

```
# partprobe /dev/sda
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `kpartx` from `sys-fs/multipath-tools`, if you modified the `/dev/sda` drive:

`# kpartx /dev/sda`

The `partx` utility from `sys-apps/util-linux` could be used instead, but it won't work with LVM.